# fullcalendar resource view block/disable timeslot range

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using the full calendar with resource view downloaded from http://ikelin.github.io/fullcalendar/ ...

I am using the "resource" as "persons". Now I would like to allocate available timeslots to the persons and full calendar should automatically "block" the no-available timeslots, so I can not create events for that resource.

I am already saving times for every day in my database like: personid, day, starttime, endtime. I was thinking to create a weekly event like "blocked" for every time < starttime and > endtime. But the problem is, those events would be seen in the normal views as well.

Any other ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find an elegant solution to make that. But I just warn user that is not possible to do that and I reload the calendar so the event back to its initial place.

This one part of my fullCalendar initialisation:

```
eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(event.resourceId))) {
        alert('You cannot move event here');
        $(selectorFullCalendar).fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    }
},
```